# Global fog does not work with deferred rendering in Unity

Tags: unity, deferred-rendering, fog

When I set deferred rendering the global fog from the Unity Standard Assets does not work, there is no fog at all. With forward rendering the global fog works. How do I add fog with deferred rendering?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue in Unity 5.4.1f1. Creating a test scene with a camera set to deferred rendering and the Global Fog script attached, I observe fog in the game preview window and when running the game. I did have to play with the density and height settings to make the fog more pronounced though - is it possible that the fog is present in your scene, but just very faint/out of view of your camera? By default Height Fog is on, which will only fog content close to the plane `y = 0` or below.

Comment: I have uploaded a video that shows the issue: https://youtu.be/WJ2RavosWXI.

Answer (score 0):

Download this: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/83912

After Downloading it attach the "Post Processing Behaviour" Script to your Main Camera. The Script comes with the Package. Right-Click into your assets folder and create a new "Post-Processing Profile". Drag that into the empty Slow in the Inspector in the newly added Script on your Main Camera.
Select the Post-Processing Profile and in the Inspector Check "Fog".